# Object instanceof Integer returns false

Tags: java, string, integer, instanceof

```
Object obj = "1234";
System.out.println(obj instanceof Integer);
```

What else should I do to check such Object if its an instanceof Integer or Float.

Comment: Because it's false. It's a String.

Comment: Reading your profile, this almost feels like a troll question - you have a masters degree in CS, you're working for IBM on banking and security applications, your major language is Java, but you don't know the difference between an Integer and a String literal? You're too late, April 1st was two days ago... But seriously, you should refresh your knowledge of the basics. [This section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/index.html) of the official tutorial deals with Strings and numbers, [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/converting.html) with conversions.

Comment: instead of checking instanceof I should parse it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it returns false because obj is not an `Integer`, it's a reference to a `String` object.

```
Object obj = "1234";

try {
    int value = ((Integer) obj);
} catch (ClassCastException e) {
    // failed
}
```

or

```
Object obj = "1234";

try {
    int value = Integer.parseInt((String)obj);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // failed
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `obj` is a `String`, the one below can return `true`

```
Object obj = new Integer(1234);
```

Or

```
Object obj = 1234;
```

Comment: I get String like "1234" as an argument. So I cannot use Object obj = 1234;

Comment: @ImranTariq If you know you have a String, why do you think it is an Integer?

Comment: There are many possible values @Joe. So it can be String, Integer, Float etc. I and checking types and changing business logic based on it

Comment: @ImranTariq Well, are they really typed as String, Integer and Float ? Or are they numbers encoded in a string ? "123.2" is a string, just as "Joe" or "53" is. If they are encoded as strings, you need to start parsing the string and guess what kind of type it might be.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
try {
    int a = Integer.parseInt("1234");
    // No need to check instance of now, if supplied argument is number
    // then parseInt() will pass otherwise you will get exception.
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println("Supplied argument is not valid number");
}
```

Comment: looks good. instead of checking instanceof I should parse it.

Answer (score 0):

Any thing between `""` is String. You are checking String against Integer that's why it's giving **false**.

Try `Object obj = 1234;`

It will change the primitive type `int` to `Integer` by **autoboxing**.

or

```
Object obj=new Integer(123);
```

Comment: @ImranTariq try this.